# How to use the ffmpeg library to transpose a video?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm trying to develop an video recorder and playback app in Android. So, I'm using the ffmpeg library and I've compiled the library to use in the project.

I record a video and when I playback, in some devices don't recognize the orientation matrix, so I want to develop with the ffmpeg library a C method to do this order:

ffmpeg -i f.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" -r 24 -sameq f2.mp4"

I found this documentation but don't help me, because don't use the AVFilter and AVFilterContext classes.

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html

http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/structAVFilterContext.html

http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/api-example_8c-source.html

Now I only have the opening and closing video file

Here my code:

```
/*open the video file*/
if ((lError = av_open_input_file(&gFormatCtx, gFileName, NULL, 0, NULL)) !=0 ) {
    LOGE(1, "Error open video file: %d", lError);
    return; //open file failed
}
/*retrieve stream information*/
if ((lError = av_find_stream_info(gFormatCtx)) < 0) {
    LOGE(1, "Error find stream information: %d", lError);
    return;
} 
/*find the video stream and its decoder*/
gVideoStreamIndex = av_find_best_stream(gFormatCtx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &lVideoCodec, 0);
if (gVideoStreamIndex == AVERROR_STREAM_NOT_FOUND) {
    LOGE(1, "Error: cannot find a video stream");
    return;
} else {
LOGI(10, "video codec: %s", lVideoCodec->name);
}
if (gVideoStreamIndex == AVERROR_DECODER_NOT_FOUND) {
    LOGE(1, "Error: video stream found, but no decoder is found!");
    return;
}   
/*open the codec*/
gVideoCodecCtx = gFormatCtx->streams[gVideoStreamIndex]->codec;
LOGI(10, "open codec: (%d, %d)", gVideoCodecCtx->height, gVideoCodecCtx->width);
#ifdef SELECTIVE_DECODING
gVideoCodecCtx->allow_selective_decoding = 1;
#endif
if (avcodec_open(gVideoCodecCtx, lVideoCodec) < 0) {
LOGE(1, "Error: cannot open the video codec!");
    return;
}
LOGI(10, "get video info ends");
```

How can I transpose the video using the ffmpeg library?

Comment: As you compiled the `ffmpeg` libs, you already are touching the code, so why not look at the sources of the `ffmpeg` tool itself?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking the code for how to use the ffmpeg library. But, I don't find a way how to connect the avfilter classes with the opened video to do the transposition.

Comment: I was referring to the code of the `ffmpeg` tool **itself**, which in turn uses the `ffmpeg libs`.

Comment: I don't know what code are you referring? I need to execute the order: ffmpeg -i f.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" -r 24 -sameq f2.mp4 using the fffmpeg library I need to execute this code in a .c file. Could you post the code you are referring, please?

Comment: `ffmpeg` builds from `ffmpeg.c` and is linked against functionality provided by the various ffmpeg libs (libav*). I was referring to `ffmpeg.c`.

Comment: beni, just for the knowledge, which version of ffmpeg you built in the android ?

Answer (score 0):

How to Using FFmpeg decode Customer I/O

```
AVCodec *pCodec;
avcodec_register_all();
// Register all formats and codecs
av_register_all();

//av_init_packet(&packet);
if(avformat_network_init()!=0){
    goto initError; // Couldn't init new work
}
// Open video file

pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
printf("==========>>%p %lu\n", buff,sizeof(buff));
pFormatCtx->pb=av_malloc(buff_size);//pFormatCtx->pb=av_alloc_put_byte(buff,buff_size,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
pFormatCtx->pb=avio_alloc_context(buff,buff_size,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

pFormatCtx->iformat=av_find_input_format("h264");
pFormatCtx->flags = AVFMT_FLAG_CUSTOM_IO;
pFormatCtx->iformat->flags=AVFMT_NOFILE;

// Retrieve stream information
 if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx,NULL)<0){
        goto initError; // Couldn't find stream information
}
 streamNo=-1;
// Find the first video stream
if ((streamNo =  av_find_best_stream(pFormatCtx,AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &pCodec, 0)) < 0)
{
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find a video stream in the input file %d\n",streamNo);
    goto initError;
}
```

While i'm Can't Find Stream from My Buffer  the streamNo allway is -1381258232
my Buffer is void* buff int buff_size